# Using a word to describe that something can be detailed

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I want to find an adjective to describe that something can be detailed.
From my google search I found that "Detailable" isn't a word.

EDIT:

I am actually trying to find an interface name for a class (Programming).
The idea is that objects that will implement the "Detailable" interface will be asked for information to show details.

Example:

> Car is detailable so I can ask which is it's description.

PS: Something similar happens with "Commentable".

Comment: Detailed how? Please edit your question to add more context, such as a representative sentence the word fits into.

Comment: Detailed like you would a car?

Comment: I just added more info with an example.

Comment: To _detail_ a car means to clean every conceivable nook and cranny.   Details about a single car would include its make, model, year, and trim line (if any).  Maybe you are looking for _classifiable_?

Comment: @cornbreadninja: That means "capable of being classified". I am looking for "capable of showing description information". The closest I found is `Describable`.

Comment: What don't you like about describable?

Comment: @MattЭллен: Nothing in particular, I will use that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some possible fits:

- Faceted (a lot of times people talk of faceted search looking at
  object attributes)
- Describable
- Information

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to use an '*-able*'-suffixed interface name.  You could simply have it implement the "*Inspection*" interface.

Answer (score 2):

Queryable?
Interrogable?
Detailable implies that it can be detailed.

Answer (score 2):

Annotated.
I think you mean 'something that can be described in further detail, or has further details available.'. The first word that comes to mind is 'annotated'.
On second thought, 'details' could be pretty vague, for an interface offering useful information about your object. For instance, if the details are actually specifications, say, speed, size, and dimensions, then your word should indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

*[Effable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/effable)* ("able to be spoken of; able to be expressed") might serve, except for being archaic.  It is antonymic to *[ineffable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ineffable)* ("beyond expression in words; unspeakable"), a word still commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

How about "has details" or "can have details"? Does it have to be a single word?

Answer (score 0):

How about "specifications" That would be appropriate for details that describe how big, fast, hot, round, expensive, etc. something is.